# Манипуляции со списком словарей

Tags: python, словари

Помогите, пожалуйста, составить код. Имеется список словарей:

```
slovar = [{code: 228, log: '08', time: datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 787903)}, 
          {code: 227, log: '18', time: datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 787903)}, 
          {code: 228, log: '56', time: datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 787903)}, 
          {code: 226, log: '82', time: datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 3, 7, 1, 3, 787903)}, 
          {code: 226, log: '76', time: datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1, 787903)}]
```

Нужно разделить словари на воображаемые группы по ключу code (то есть, чтобы они как будто поделились на группы. В одной группе словари с code: 228, в другой code: 227 и тд)

После надо отсортировать эти "воображаемые группы" по ключу time и получить самый актуальный по времени словарь из каждой группы, после чего взять из каждого словаря значения ключей code и log и сформировать из них словарь вида {code: log, code: log и тд}

Для понимания, на выходе после всех манипуляций должно быть так:

```
>>>{228: '08', 
    227: '18', 
    226: '76'}
```

Comment: @Namerek *получить самый актуальный*

Comment: нет нет, именно так, как я указал на выходе. То есть, сделать словарь, где ключ - значение ключа code, а значение - значение ключа log

Comment: изменил условие. Ошибся в предпоследнем абзаце "После надо отсортировать..." в последней его строчке. Написал изначально "значения ключей code и time...", исправил на "значения ключей code и log". Прошу прощения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего через `Pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

slovar = [{'code': 228, 'log': '08', 'time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 227, 'log': '18', 'time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 228, 'log': '56', 'time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 226, 'log': '82', 'time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 3, 7, 1, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 226, 'log': '76', 'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1, 787903)}]

df = pd.DataFrame(slovar)
result = df.sort_values('time').groupby('code')['log'].last().to_dict()
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
{226: '76', 227: '18', 228: '08'}
```

Можно и на чистом питоне сделать, но код будет чуть сложнее и при этом код будет менее понятный с виду:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

slovar = [{'code': 228, 'log': '08', 'time': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 1, 7, 6, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 227, 'log': '18', 'time': datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 2, 7, 8, 1, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 228, 'log': '56', 'time': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 226, 'log': '82', 'time': datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 3, 7, 1, 3, 787903)}, 
          {'code': 226, 'log': '76', 'time': datetime.datetime(2018, 9, 1, 5, 6, 1, 787903)}]

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in slovar:
    d[item['code']].append((item['time'], item['log']))
result = {k: sorted(v)[-1][1] for k, v in d.items()}
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
{228: '08', 227: '18', 226: '76'}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, но можно, пожалуйста, обойтись без модуля pandas? Используя itertools, например

Comment: Можно. Кстати да, наверное можно было `groupby` взять из `itertools`, но мне тогда проще без него вообще.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо огромное! Последний вопросик: допустим, что таких списков, как slovar несколько, но все они лежат в одном списке. То есть, [ [ {словарь1}, {словарь2} ], [ {словарь3{, {словарь4} ] ] . Предположим, что мы сделали все вышеупомянутые манипуляции с этими списками, но теперь их надо объединить в один словарь. Как это сделать?  (то есть, отталкиваясь полностью от того же условия задачи). Я попробовал вот так вот, но теперь не знаю, как избавиться от типа list (код в следующем комментарии)

Comment: Я поставил слеш, где есть переносы строки / result = [] / 
for i in slovar: /  
    df = pd.DataFrame(i) /
    res = df.sort_values('time').groupby('code')['log'].last().to_dict() /
    result.append(res)

Comment: Словари не пересекаются? Тогда просто используйте словарь, а не список: `result = {}` ... `result.update(res)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, за беспокойство, но можно ли сделать так, чтобы первый ваш код через pandas выводил значения в том порядке, в котором они в slovar? Имею ввиду, у вас вывод: {226: '76', 227: '18', 228: '08'}, а чтобы он был как у меня {228: '08', 227: '18',  226: '76'}. И тут дело не в sorted. Скорее всего, это можно обьяснить так: идем по спискам со словарями и выводим правильные значения, которые нам встречаются, в том порядке, в котором они находятся

Comment: Если порядок важен, то решение с `pandas` надо переписывать - сначала тогда делать группировку, а потом уже сортировку. А это настолько важно? Вообще словари это такая структура, которая не всегда предполагает устойчивую сортировку по ключу. Если нужно, я потом код перепишу, там не совсем просто.

Comment: Боже, я не понял, что произошло, но мой ответ приняли!) Я хотел написать вам о том, как переделал ваш второй код с collections, но его не приняли и выдавали ошибку, связанную с str и индексацией, но сейчас я просто решил вставить этот код еще раз, чтобы я мог скопировать ошибку и отправить вам, и тут вдруг сайт принял мое решение! Так что можете не волноваться над переделкой кода, спасибо вам огромное преогромное, что помогали мне! Доброго вам дня и хорошего настроения! ^^

Comment: @DaniilDemchenko Главное чтобы вы поняли, как этот код собственно работает. Простое копирование чужих решений без понимания их сути вас ничему не научит :)

Comment: на самом деле, я действительно не очень понимаю. Буду рад, если вы мне обьясните: я в принципе понял, что делает for  d[item['code']].append((item['time'], item['log'])), но не совсем понимаю, зачем это надо. Прошу вас обьяснить, что делает result = {k: sorted(v)[-1][1] for k, v in d.items()} по порядку. Я вот совсем не понимаю, что за k: и так далее. Думаю, если пойму это, то пойму, зачем нам нужен вид словаря, который делает for

Comment: Это **словарное сокращение**. Примерно как **списковое сокращение**, только делает оно словарь. На основе старого словаря я делаю новый. Сортирую список каждого элемента словаря по дате (для этого она и нужна в списке первым элементом кортежа), потом беру последний элемент сортированного списка и выкидываю дату, она больше не нужна.

Comment: понял, спасибо! Сам ещё немножко поэкспериментировал, хаха